# Xamarin forms ImageSource for sprite animation?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am wanting to put a little animated logo on my Xamarin Form.

it basically works but it looks terrible.  IE flickers

it appears that is either the ImageSource.FromFile() is *lazy* and loads the file from storage every time it is accessed, or setting the Image.Source is not buffered and causes tearing/flickering, or both?

i'm new to xamarin, i've never had this problem working in native java/obj-c before.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Is there any way to force the ImageSource to actually pre-load into memory?  Is there a way to update the Image.Source property without flicker?  Or should I try to move to an XamarinIOS/Android custom (native) control?

```cs
 public partial class SplashIntro : ContentPage {

    ImageSource[] sprites = new ImageSource[17];

    public SplashIntro() {
      InitializeComponent();
      LoadSplashImages();
      this.Appearing += SplashIntro_Appearing;
    }

    private void SplashIntro_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      PlayAni();
    }

    void LoadSplashImages() {
      for (int i = 0; i < sprites.Length; i++) {
        ImageSource ims = ImageSource.FromFile($"logani{i + 1}.png");
        sprites[i] = ims;
      }
    }

    void PlayAni() {
      aniImage.Source = sprites[0];
      int nextFrame = 1;
      Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(80), () => {
        //  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { aniImage.Source = sprites[nextFrame]; });
        aniImage.Source = sprites[nextFrame];
        nextFrame++;
        if (nextFrame == sprites.Length) nextFrame = 0;
        return true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried on a real device? I know I have seen a few cases where the simulator will flicker but the real device is smooth.

Comment: yes, this is on the device.  i don't even bother with the android simulator anymore ;o(

Comment: I think you're probably pushing the envelope as far as what Forms is designed to do.  For sprite animation I would implement it in the platform layer.

Comment: As Jason said, sprites may have issues in a Forms scenario. The following post from Jason Smith offers some ideas on how to do basic animations with UI Elements, which may assist in achieving the same goal: http://xfcomplete.net/animation/2016/01/18/compound-animations/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing this via a Custom Renderer would be the best way in order to leavage each platform's features:

**iOS**: This can be done via applying an array of `UIImage`s to a `UIImageView.AnimationImage` property.

**Android**: *One way*, is to set a "animation-list" drawable to the background of `ImageView`.

[image]

(the gif is glitchy, but these two techniques run smooth on devices (and most emulators ;-)

Note: This example code uses 10 images (`frame_X.png`) that are linked under iOS **Resources** and Android **Resources/drawable**.

#### `Xamarin.Forms` Custom `Image` Control w/ bindable `Animate` property:

```
public class AnimatedImage : Image
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AnimateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Animate",
        returnType: typeof(bool),
        declaringType: typeof(AnimatedImage),
        defaultValue: false);

    public bool Animate
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AnimateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnimateProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

#### iOS Custom `ImageRenderer`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AnimatedImage), typeof(AnimatedImageRenderer_iOS))]
namespace AnimImage.iOS
{
    public class AnimatedImageRenderer_iOS : ImageRenderer
    {
        const int imageCount = 10;
        NSMutableArray imageArray;
        public AnimatedImageRenderer_iOS() {
            imageArray = new NSMutableArray(imageCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
                imageArray.Add(UIImage.FromFile(new NSString($"frame_{i}.png")));
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.AnimationImages = NSArray.FromArray<UIImage>(imageArray);
                Control.AnimationDuration = 1;
                Control.AnimationRepeatCount = 0;
                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    if ((e.NewElement as AnimatedImage).Animate)
                        Control.StartAnimating();
                }
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == "Animate")
            {
                if ((sender as AnimatedImage).Animate)
                    Control?.StartAnimating();
                else
                    Control?.StopAnimating();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Android Custom `ImageRenderer`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AnimatedImage), typeof(AnimatedImageRenderer_Droid))]
namespace AnimImage.Droid
{
    public class AnimatedImageRenderer_Droid : ImageRenderer
    {
        public AnimatedImageRenderer_Droid() { }

        AnimationDrawable anim;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.animatedlogo);
                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    if ((e.NewElement as AnimatedImage).Animate)
                    {
                        (Control.Background as AnimationDrawable)?.Start();
                        Control.ImageAlpha = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == "Animate")
            {
                if ((sender as AnimatedImage).Animate)
                {
                    (Control.Background as AnimationDrawable)?.Start();
                    Control.ImageAlpha = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    Control.ImageAlpha = 255;
                    (Control.Background as AnimationDrawable)?.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Android `animation-list` Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_0" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_1" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_2" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_3" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_4" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_5" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_6" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_7" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_8" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_9" android:duration="100" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer!  i had already done this with android, using the animation-list, and yes it is smooth.  (and came back to answer my own, but you beat me to it, with ios too :)